# Erro ao criar um campo NOT NULL no PGADMIN " contém valores nulos "

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, pgadmin

Eu tenho um *database* já criada, dentro dela eu tenho uma tabela já criada. Nela eu preciso criar um campo que seja `NOT NULL`. Eu faço tudo pela interface gráfica que é mais rápida, eu clico na tabela `> new column :`, dou um nome, digo o tipo e marco a opção `NOT NULL`. Quando eu marco a opção NOT NULL e clico em OK, salvar aparece o seguinte erro:

> AN ERROR OCCURRED:
>
> Coluna: "Nome" contém valores nulos.

Utilizo a versão do PGADMIN III.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A própria mensagem dá uma boa indicação do problema. Duas coisas podem acontecer:

1. Está criando uma nova coluna e não está colocando um valor `DEFAULT` nela. Desta forma ela pode ser nula. Estabeleça um valor `DEFAULT` que garanta a não nulidade se nada for passado. Se não quer manter este *default*, depois pode dar um `DROP DEFAULT`.
2. Você está transformando uma coluna que aceitava valores e nulos e de fato existem estes valores em algumas das linhas contidas na tabela. Quando você quer impor esta restrição para a coluna todas as linhas precisam estar de acordo com ela. Antes você precisa resolver o problema das linhas para depois conseguir aplicar a nova restrição. Não há como o banco de dados resolver isto sozinho, você tem que tomar providências, você tem que colocar valores válidos nesta coluna em todas as linhas contidas na tabela. Depois disto a restrição poderá ser aplicada porque todas as linhas conseguem atendê-la.

Comment: Opa, Obrigado pela resposta. Mas é que não é isso, eu estou criando uma nova coluna, ela não existia antes e não há dados nulos em uma coluna que é criada no momento.

Comment: Veja se resolve agora.

Comment: Sim, dessa forma eu consigo inserir um novo campo como NOT NULL. Obrigado

Comment: @EstácioDiFabio você sabe que você também pode votar nas respostas? Não só em perguntas que você fez, você pode votar em tudo no *site*. Veja o [tour]. Seria legal você dar uma revisada pelo menos em tudo o que você já postou e ver se o que postaram merece seu voto.